# Existing icons are not visible on the properties tab

Tags: properties

Existing icons are not visible on the properties tab.As in the second image below, there were various tabs, but they disappeared. Even if I delete and reinstall the blender app, I don't get a few tabs.
'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please clarify your problem?

Comment: As in the second image below, there were various tabs, but they disappeared.

Comment: If you don't select an object, you won't have the tabs related to objects.

Comment: Is it possible that the visible tabs are pinned? Or that you have the camera or the light selected?